# Firebase Security rules issues

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I Have the following security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read":"auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      }
    },
  }
}
```

In my app the user is registered as such

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            String UID = mCurrent.getUid();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //Get the details from our UserHelperClass
          
                UserHelperClass helperClass = new UserHelperClass();
                helperClass.setName(name);
                helperClass.setContactNumber(contactNumber);
                helperClass.setEmail(email);
                helperClass.setEmergencyContact(emergencyContact);
                helperClass.setPhoneNo(phoneNo);
                helperClass.setDob(dob);
                helperClass.setPlayerID(playerID);
                helperClass.setUid(UID);
    
  ........ //Get an instance of the firebase database and add the details from helper class to a new UID node
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(UID)
                        .setValue(helperClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

I want the any authenticated user to see the info while any profile updates should be carried out by the person with the authorised UID. When I run this the access to the read is denied logcat says permission denied

> Listen at /Users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

and I have a profile page in my app and all the info is blank. However if I click into the info to edit it it will update and display it in the app.
Also If I remove the "Users" part from the rules I can see the info but cannot update.
Any ideas what the issue is I want to use these rules and all documentation/videos seem to suggest this approach but cannot get them implemented. Also in the rules playground , I can get the read at the path, with the authenticated UID to pass

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem. Security rules on their own do nothing, without code that exercises them.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: The error message doesn't look related to the code you have here.  The message says the error is with a "listen" (read) operation, but the only database operation you have here is a write.  Please edit the question to show the code that actually triggers this error.

Comment: Also, you have created a publicly readable database that contains private info such as emails and phone numbers. Making this readable by anybody with `auth != null` is not sufficient. Please reconsider sharing user data in this way.

Comment: If you want to make this question actionable and get some quality answers, I recommend checking out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is my user node
“Users”: {
“UID”: {
“contactNumber:”
“dob:”
“email:”
“emergencyContact:”
“name:”
“phoneNo:”
“playerID:”
}    What rules are best to ensure that the user can see and update their data